# Docker y Nodemon (Forever)

Tags: nodejs, ubuntu, docker, docker-compose, sailsjs

Tengo un inconveniente al momento de usar mi contenedor. Hasta ahora, he podido crear y generar las dependencias necesarias, incluso con la ayuda de `docker-compose` logré montar los volúmenes adecuadamente. Pero poseo un inconveniente y es al momento de usar mi aplicación con un demonizador como `nodemon` o `forever` (he probado con ambos y el funcionamiento es el mismo). Básicamente lo que ocurre es que aunque los cambios que hago en mi maquina se ven reflejados en el contenedor, aun así, el demonizador no vuelve a arrancar el servidor. Les dejo mis archivos para que me puedan dar una mano:

***Dockerfile***:

```
FROM node:8.10

COPY package.json /usr/src/

WORKDIR /usr/src

RUN npm install

# RUN npm install -g nodemon
RUN npm install -g forever

COPY . /usr/src/

EXPOSE 1337

# CMD ["nodemon", "-w", "api", "-w", "config"]
CMD ["forever", "-w", "start", "app.js"]
```

***docker-compose.yml***

```
version: "3"

services:
  app:
    build: .
    depends_on:
      - db
    environment:
      MYSQL_URL: "mysql://db:3306/app"
    ports:
      - "3000:1337"
    volumes:
      - /c/Users/German/Documents/Prueba/DockerSails/:/usr/src/
      - /usr/src/node_modules
  db:
    image: mysql
    environment:
      MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD: "true"
```

***package.json***

```
{
  "name": "docker-sails",
  "private": true,
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "description": "a Sails application",
  "keywords": [],
  "dependencies": {
    "sails": "^1.1.0",
    "sails-hook-orm": "^2.1.1",
    "sails-hook-sockets": "^1.5.5",
    "@sailshq/lodash": "^3.10.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@sailshq/eslint": "^4.19.3",
    "nodemon": "^1.18.9"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "NODE_ENV=production node app.js",
    "test": "npm run lint && npm run custom-tests && echo 'Done.'",
    "lint": "eslint . --max-warnings=0 --report-unused-disable-directives && echo '✔  Your .js files look good.'",
    "custom-tests": "echo \"(No other custom tests yet.)\" && echo",
    "dev": "nodemon"
  },
  "main": "app.js",
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "git://github.com/german/docker-sails.git"
  },
  "author": "german",
  "license": "",
  "engines": {
    "node": "^8.10"
  }
}
```

Arranco normal con `docker-compose up --build -d`. Luego cuando ya ha arrancado el servidor, realizo un cambio en algún archivo dentro de mi código, luego con el comando `docker-compose exec app /bin/bash` navego hasta el archivo en mi contenedor y verifico que efectivamente se hizo el cambio. Sin embargo, cuando recargo la página, no hay cambios. Y cuando reviso los logs, el servidor nunca se reinició. Sin embargo, probando hacer el cambio directamente en el contenedor, si se reinicia el servidor gracias a `nodemon` o a `forever`. Estoy bastante desconcertado por este funcionamiento ya que en local todo me funciona adecuadamente también.

Espero que puedan ayudarme pronto con esto :)

*NOTA*: Cabe resaltar que me encuentro trabajando en Windows 10 Home, por lo que utilizo virtualbox para el demonio de docker. Sin embargo, tengo el cliente por medio de WSL en ubuntu

Comment: Tenes a mano el `packeage.json` para poder ver la configuracion del nodemon.

Comment: Si lo tengo, pero sin embargo, si te das cuenta estoy usando nodemon de manera global y no en el proyecto. lo subiré aún así si sirve de algo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

He encontrado la solución en [este enlace](https://github.com/docker/labs/issues/378)

Al parecer es necesario que pasemos la opción `-L` (Legacy) a `nodemon` para que funcionara correctamente.

Mi comando quedaría de la siguiente forma:

```
CMD ["nodemon", "-L", "-w", "api", "-w", "config"]
```